# PowerShell script can't open a file when run as a scheduled task

Tags: powershell, com

My PowerShell (2.0) script has the following code snippet:

```
$fileName = "c:\reports\1.xlsx"
$xl = new-object -comobject excel.application
$xlFormat = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.excel.XlFileFormat]::xlWorkbookDefault
$xl.displayalerts = $false
$workbook = $xl.workbooks.open($fileName)
#Code to manipulate a worksheet
$workbook.SaveAs($fileName, $xlformat)
$xl.quit()
$error | out-file c:\reports\error.txt
```

I can run this script in the PowerShell command prompt without any issues. The spreadsheet gets updated, and error.txt is empty. However, when I run it as a task in [Task Scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler), I get errors with the first line.

> Exception calling "Open" with "1" argument(s): "Microsoft Office Excel cannot access the file 'C:\reports\1.xlsx'. There are several possible reasons:
>   The file name or path does not exist.
>   The file is being used by another program.
>   The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.

I run the task with the same credentials I use to run the script in the PowerShell command prompt. When I run the script manually, it can open, update, and save the spreadsheet without any issues. When I run it in Task Scheduler, it can't access the spreadsheet.

The file in question is readable/writeable for all users. I've verified I can open the file in [Excel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel) with the same credentials. If I make a new spreadsheet and put its name in as the $filename, I get the same results. I've verified that there are no instances of Excel.exe in [Task Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Manager).

Oddly, if I use [Get-Content](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849787.aspx), I don't have any problems. Also, if I make a new spreadsheet, I don't have any problem.

```
$fileName = "c:\reports\1.xlsx"
$xl = get-content $filename
$xl = new-object -comobject excel.application
$xlFormat = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.excel.XlFileFormat]::xlWorkbookDefault
$xl.displayalerts = $false
# Commented out $workbook = $xl.workbooks.open($fileName)
$workbook = $xl.workbooks.add()
#Code to manipulate a worksheet
$workbook.SaveAs($fileName, $xlformat)
$xl.quit()
$error | out-file c:\reports\error.txt
```

That works fine. So [Get-ChildItem](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx) can open the file without any issue. ComObject can open the file if I run it manually, but not if it's run as task.

I'm at a loss. Any ideas?

Comment: Spend some time adding some more error checking to your script.  What What happens if you `test-path $fileName`?  What happens if you `Test-Path "c:\reports".  Also, are you sure sure the file **isn't open by another program**?

Comment: That was the point of adding "Get-Content $filename". BTW, I had a typo; $spreadsheet was supposed to be $filename. Anywat, if Get-Content succeeded (and it did), that indicated that Powershell could reach and read the file. In any event, I went ahead and add "test-path c:\reports" to the script. That command completed with no errors.

Comment: Does taking the quotes out of the filename help? (`$fileName = c:\reports\1.xlsx`)

Answer (score 1):

Add the *-No Profile* switch to powershell.exe in your scheduled task (edit your task, go to the *Actions* tab, edit your action and in *Add arguments* field, add *-No Profile* as the first argument.)

Comment: Care to expand?

Comment: Always run scheduled scripts with -Noprofile, check this for completeness https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/console/powershell.exe-command-line-help - oh, and triple check that it runs with the credentials you want it to run under. Log in with those and test or use RunAs. It's often the simple things. :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106381/microsoft-office-excel-cannot-access-the-file-c-inetpub-wwwroot-timesheet-app

You just have to do this:

1. Create directory "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop "
   (for 64 bit Windows) or
   "C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop " (for 32 bit
   Windows)
2. Set Full control permissions for directory Desktop (for example in
   Win7 & IIS 7 & DefaultAppPool set permissions for user "IIS
   AppPool\DefaultAppPool")

It worked for me! Hope it helps